# Dropzone JS Unpermitted Parameters In Rails 4

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, paperclip, dropzone.js

I've been struggling with this issue all night. I'm trying to upload multiple "Photo" models with Dropzone.js with the paperclip attribute "attachment". Currently I'm using the DropZone-Rails gem (I've tried several versions all with same result).

```
# photo.rb

class Photo < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_attached_file :attachment, styles: { medium: "720x720>", thumb: "360x360>" }, default_url: "/images/:style/missing.png"
  validates_attachment_content_type :attachment, content_type: /\Aimage\/.*\Z/
  belongs_to :gallery
  belongs_to :user

end
```

As you can see below, I've whitelisted the attachment parameter.

```
#photos_controller.rb
class PhotosController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_photo, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]


.........

private

# Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
def set_photo
  @photo = Photo.find(params[:id])
end

# Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
def photo_params

  params.require(:photo).permit(:attachment, :gallery_id)

end
```

DropZone loads as expected, configured here with:
  Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;

In my template:

```
  $("#new_photo").dropzone({  
    // restrict photo size to a maximum 1MB
    maxFilesize: 4,

    paramName: "photo[attachment]",

    addRemoveLinks: true,
    uploadMultiple: true,

    success: function(file, response){
      $(file.previewTemplate).find('.dz-remove').attr('id', response.fileID);
      $(file.previewElement).addClass("dz-success");
    }

  }); 

  var myDropzone = new Dropzone();
```

My form with DropZone's fallback:

```
<%= form_for(Photo.new, html: { multipart: true, class: "dropzone"}) do |f|  %>
  <%= f.hidden_field :gallery_id, :value=>@gallery.id %>
  <div class="fallback">
    <%= f.file_field :attachment %>

    <%= f.submit "Upload" %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

My log's output for params is (before getting filtered):

```
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓",     "authenticity_token"=>"5ftDcdfB1YpL4UF1fupC/I11xRx3HV5GYih5kshO/KSXzSrZS5Iu1wVRhbLFiyfQWQbwP3R5mxeoJLiM+cUJDg==", "photo"=>{"gallery_id"=>"13", "attachment"=>{"0"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x007f8058e13c48 @tempfile=#<Tempfile:/var/folders/jb/f02hpkhs3813_b6w_bvyxkxw0000gn/T/RackMultipart20170419-16050-8s5zd8.jpg>, @original_filename="624bbbf5b3c8a293950c8ed24a0c4eef.jpg", @content_type="image/jpeg", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"photo[attachment][0]\"; filename=\"624bbbf5b3c8a293950c8ed24a0c4eef.jpg\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n">}}}
```

This leads to:

```
Unpermitted parameter: attachment
{"gallery_id"=>"13"}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I've searched everything and tried everything and can't seem to make it work. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your model `Photo` definition, it is clear that you want to upload 1 attachment file per record. But the params you are receiving in your controller are those for uploading multiple attachments.

```
{ ..., attachment => { 0 => #<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile }, ... }
```

If you want to permit only 1 attachment in your params, your params should be in form:

```
{ ..., attachment => #<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile, ... }
```

Looking at the [dropzone options](http://www.dropzonejs.com/#config-uploadMultiple), i would say, try to change `uploadMultiple: true` to `uploadMultiple: false` in drop zone configuration. Let me know, if the problem still persists.

Comment: And you are correct! I spent way too much time on this. Thank you!